# ng serve "Cannot GET /"

Tags: angular, angular12

After upgrade to Angular 12, i can not serve the dev server on localhost:4200.

There are only one error if i run `ng serve`:

```
Error: /var/www/html/stuff2angular/assets/css/style.scss:10:32: Unknown word
You tried to parse SCSS with the standard CSS parser; try again with the postcss-scss parser
```

`ng build` has no errors and produce a working app.

Disable Ivy do not help.

My angular.json:

```js
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "stuff2angular": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@ngrx/schematics:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "arcr",
      "i18n": {
        "locales": {
          "de": "src/locale/messages.de.xlf",
          "en": "src/locale/messages.en.xlf"
        }
      },
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/stuff2angular",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": true,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/assets/css/style.scss",
              "src/assets/css/basics.scss",
              "src/assets/font/fontawesome/css/all.css"
            ],
            "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
              "includePaths": [
                "src/assets/css"
              ]
            },
            "scripts": [
              "src/assets/font/fa-custom.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "stuff2angular:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "stuff2angular:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "stuff2angular:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
              "src/basics.scss",
              "src/w3schools.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "stuff2angular:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "stuff2angular:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "stuff2angular",
  "cli": {
    "defaultCollection": "@ngrx/schematics",
    "analytics": "31d612d1-4061-47ae-8168-c83cb1adf86e"
  }
}
```

The browser say: 404 localhost:4200

It looks like the server is not running.

Delete the folder /node_modules and run `npm install` change nothing.

What can i do? Any Idea?

[edit]

OS: Ubuntu 20.04

`ng v`:

```
Angular CLI: 12.0.0
Node: 14.17.0
Package Manager: npm 6.14.13
OS: linux x64

Angular: 12.0.0
... animations, cdk, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core
... forms, language-service, localize, material
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1200.0
@angular-devkit/build-angular   12.0.0
@angular-devkit/core            12.0.0
@angular-devkit/schematics      12.0.0
@schematics/angular             12.0.0
rxjs                            6.6.7
typescript                      4.2.4
```

The app was created with CLI.

My app was upgraded from 11 to 12, see [update.angular.io](https://update.angular.io/?l=2&v=11.0-12.0).

Comment: Could be multiple things we'd need a [mcve]. Have you seen this issue https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2243

Comment: i have read the issue and it can not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inline comments in *.scss were the problem for the error message.

And without the css errors, the local dev server works.

Strange that CSS problems kill the server.